# Graphgql parameter passing error 'Synatax error: unexpected $' for integer?

Tags: graphql

Here is my query

```
  $locale: String! = "$locale"
  $searchKey: String! = "$searchKey"
  $contentType: String! = "$contentType"
  $start : Int = $start
  $limit : Int = $limit
) {
  contents(
    locale: $locale
    start: $start
    limit:  $limit
    sort: "priority:asc"
    where: {
      _or: [
        { title_contains: $searchKey }
        { keywords_contains: $searchKey } 
      ]
      ct_lookup: { code_contains: $contentType }
    }
  ) {
    id
    title
    
  }
}
```

and I'm passing parameters

```
{
  "locale":"sv",
  "searchKey":"",
  "contentType":"",
  "start": 4,
  "limit": 2
  
  
}
```

In the **query** in 4th line I get an error "Synatax error: unexpected $"
the line is `$start : Int = $start`. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set default values to your params.

```
  $locale: String! = "$locale" <-- defaultValue
  $searchKey: String! = "$searchKey" <-- defaultValue
  $contentType: String! = "$contentType" <-- defaultValue
  $start : Int = $start <-- defaultValue
  $limit : Int = $limit <-- defaultValue
```

Your params should look like this:

```
 $locale: String!
 $searchKey: String!
 $contentType: String!
 $start : Int
 $limit : Int
```